# ssh tunnel - how to enable timeouts?

Tags: ssh

I often temporarily and quickly (ad-hoc) want to tunnel http traffic (and other protocols also) from one server to another using an ssh tunnel. I use for this (at source server):

```
ssh -f -n -L *:80:target-server.com:80 target-server.com sleep 11555200
```

Problem is that after a while there is hundreds of connections that I'll see by

```
lsof -n -i:80

ssh     17076 root    5u  IPv6 425353159       TCP <source-serverIP>:http->173.245.48.218:52116 (ESTABLISHED)
ssh     17076 root    8u  IPv6 425352908       TCP <source-serverIP>:http->82.177.80.10:49936 (FIN_WAIT2)
ssh     17076 root    9u  IPv6 425353148       TCP <source-serverIP>:http->173.245.48.218:31791 (ESTABLISHED)
ssh     17076 root   10u  IPv6 425353029       TCP <source-serverIP>:http->80.125.175.214:49837 (FIN_WAIT2)
ssh     17076 root   11u  IPv6 425353100       TCP <source-serverIP>:http->90.10.149.220:47749 (FIN_WAIT2)
ssh     17076 root   12u  IPv6 425353160       TCP <source-serverIP>:http->79.22.138.109:60744 (ESTABLISHED)
ssh     17076 root   13u  IPv6 425353105       TCP <source-serverIP>:http->90.10.149.220:53312 (FIN_WAIT2)
```

Those connections never seem to timeout. And when number of those reaches ~1024 tunnel does not accept new connections at all. What should I do for these connections timeout like it would without tunnel?

```
# lsof -n -i:80|grep 'FIN_WAIT2'|wc -l
1016
```

changing `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout` to a small value does not fix anything.

Also this issue seems to happen only with tunneled http traffic (maybe https too). With tunneling pop3/imap I saw no such issues.

Also I wonder how to change max limit of open tunnel connection to > 1024. I tied

```
ulimit -n 99999 ssh -f -n -L *:80:target-server.com:80 target-server.com 'ulimit -n 99999 && sleep 11555200'
```

but it does not fix it. Also setting `tcp_max_orphans` to a high value does not affect this.

Comment: You need a proper VPN.

Comment: Not really. It is very difficult to tunel only selected tcp port traffic via vpn if not almost impossible, not to mention is requires configuration changes on both sites and that is hardly ad-hoc material.

Comment: Look into policy routing.

Answer (score 1):

There are three sets of commands that enable connection keepalives.

`TCPKeepAlive`
`ServerAliveInterval` combined with `ServerAliveCountMax`
`ClientAliveInterval` combined with `ClientAliveCountMax`

`TCPKeepAlive` keeps a connection alive by sending a keepalive OUTSIDE of the standard ssh encryption, meaning any networking equipment can see that it's just a keepalive.  This is spoofable.  This method is not recommended.

`ServerAliveInterval` is initiated by the CLIENT.  `ServerAliveCountMax` will set a maximum number of keepalives to send, after which a disconnect occurs.

`ClientAliveInterval` is the same as `ServerAliveInterval` except it is initiated by the Server.

Ensure that all three options are not being invoked.  Check `$HOME/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Comment: As far as I gathered these options does not affect connection open via ssh tunelling but original ssh connection only - which should not and does not timeout. I use default ssh and sshd values on both sides and that means TCPKeepAlive is on so dead connections ssh are detected, however apparently not tunneled connections.

Comment: The only keepalive that matters is the SSH connection.  All machines between `Host A` and `Host B` only see an SSH connection.  It does not see tunnels.  It does not see that you're using `vi` on a file.  It does not see that your tunnel is streaming the latest episode of Breaking Bad.  It sees SSH.  The SSH connection is the only thing that needs the keepalive.  The SSH connection cannot and will not time out one of the tunnels.  If the tunnel has timed out, so has the SSH connection itself.

Answer (score 1):

You had it right the first time, except for the sleep delay.. which is in seconds! try a smaller value, for me this works (will close in 5 minutes):

ssh -f -n -L *:80:target-server.com:80 target-server.com sleep 300